# How to log to stdout in Firefox C++ code?

Tags: c++, debugging, firefox, logging

I am trying to write a patch for Firefox and have problem getting my debug messages in the console or system's journals.

I often use printing to stdout instead of using debug tools and it proved to be not trivial in Firefox. So far I have built Firefox with mach withdebugging enabled:

```
$ hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-unified && cd mozilla-unified
$ ./mach configure --enable-debug --disable-optimize
$ ./mach build
```

I tried logging with `printf` and by defining a logger:

```
using mozilla::LogLevel;
static mozilla::LazyLogModule sLogger("example_logger");
```

and then logging debug messages this way:

```
MOZ_LOG(sLogger, LogLevel::Debug, ("The debug message goes here."));
// or
printf("What is going on here?");
```

I run Firefox with setting the verbosity flag to max level for my debugger:

```
MOZ_LOG="example_logger:5" ./mach run
```

I have modified `mozilla-unified/editor/libeditor/EditorEventListener.cpp` and I assume it is being instantiated. However none of these changes yielded any message printed to the console.

P.S. Before asking here I tried #introduction and #developers on irc.mozilla.org for two days and no body answered. I also read MDN docs but it mostly covers debugging and many of the pages are outdated (from 2000).

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: No, I'm on Archlinux.